# How to pass value to and join correlated query having WITH clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to pass from one select value to another one to get the calculation done and join the results but having problem with this "with" clause sub query.

This one calculates balance from supplied number **loan_id** from the second query

```
WITH my_select (balance, type) As
(
    select sum(amount_o-amount_h) as balance, type 
    from decret d 
    where d.idnumber = **loan_id** 
      and d.DATE_D <= '2013-10-31'  
      and type in (1,2,3,4,11,12,13,18,20,25)
    group by type
    having sum(amount_o-amount_h) <> 0
)
select sum(balance) FROM my_select    //just returns client balance
```

And this one selects clients data and I want for every client add the balance also to the result calculated in first query.

```
SELECT *, /*balance*/ from clients
where  **loan_id** in (select LoanNum 
                       from NumsFromEx)
```

How to join them together?  (I have simplified a little bit queries to show it cleaner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the sample queries, the following should work:

```
WITH cteBalances AS
(
    SELECT loan_id, SUM(amount_o-amount_h) AS balance 
    FROM decret d 
    WHERE d.DATE_D <= '2013-10-31'  
      AND type IN (1,2,3,4,11,12,13,18,20,25)
    GROUP BY loan_id
)
SELECT c.*, b.balance 
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN cteBalances b ON b.loan_id = c.loan_id
WHERE  loan_id IN (SELECT LoanNum 
                   FROM NumsFromEx)
```

Comment: Hi, testing this right now but for now somehow getting way too many records then I should. Will update.

Comment: Hi Zulu its unclear exactly what result you're trying to select, which is why my query is probably wrong. The easiest way for me to advise you would be if you're able to show me some simple example data for the tables `decret` and `clients` and then the result you would expect to see based on that data.

Comment: I'm surprised it would give you too many records though, it should give you exactly 1 record per client whose `loan_id` is in `NumsFromEx`

Comment: we forgot to put having sum(amount_o-amount_h)<>0 after group by :) now works fine, thanks a lot!